# Undo git ignore settings for a directory

Tags: git, gitignore

The repo's main `.gitignore` successfully ignores build artefacts in the "bin" folder with the rule:

`[Bb]in/`

However, a folder buried in the repo's directory tree is called "bin" and contains files that should be tracked. Navigating to the folder in `git bash` and issuing `git check-ignore` produces the following output

```
USER MINGW64 /h/Work/REPO/Folder1/Folder2/bin (MyBranch)
$ git check-ignore -v test.bat
.gitignore:24:[Bb]in/   test.bat
```

As expected, the rule from the main `.gitignore` is indeed responsible for the file being ignored.

After adding a `.gitignore` into Folder1/Folder2/bin, I cannot get the syntax right to undo the ignore rule. Have tried all of the following:

```
![Bb]in/
!.bat
!test.bat
```

But the result is always the same: `test.bat` is ignored because of the base `.gitignore`. What is the correct syntax to create an exception? I'd like to try for a single file and an entire directory name.

Comment: Couldn't you have avoided all that using `/[Bb]in`? This should only ignore the immediate bin directory, relative to the ignore file.

Comment: @JeffMercado: The main `.gitignore` was set up by someone else, and some improvements can be made along the lines you suggest. In this particular case, I think the author wanted to catch general "bin" folders, so what they've done wasn't terrible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the directory structure in `.gitignore`

```bash
#.gitignore
package-lock.json
!jeremy/test/package-lock.json
```

For a single file, you can indicate it as above.

[image: example]

For a directory, you would use below which would allow all files in `test/`. The trick for a directory is the trailing `/*` and an asterisk.

for example, if you have a nested directory for `node_modules` in `test`, it would still pass

```bash
!jeremy/test/*
```

[image: example 2]

Comment: I think I figured it out: Because the `[Bb]in` rule was blocking the "bin" sub-folder, there was no way to create exceptions from within that ignored folder. So nothing works. But I used your suggestion to create a `### General exceptions ###` section in the main .`gitignore` for the repo, suppling the full path to the sub-folder...and that works.